# Inkscape - lock the length of some paths?

Tags: inkscape, laser-cutting

I have a 2d model for a laser cutter. It has cutouts where the wooden layer fits in perpendicularly. That means the cutout has to have the exact width so the layer fits in.

Now I am experimenting with the right size of the whole model.
That, however, means that after every size change, I have to change the width of all cut-outs back to the right size (2.7 mm).

```
_________________
|     _____     |
|_____|   |_____|
```

Is there a way to lock certain path segments length so that it doesn't change when resizing?

(The rest would accomodate)

Comment: No, use a parametric cad application.

Comment: As an Inkscape user, I have occasionally lamented the lack of "locking" or having parametric options within the program. I found some usefulness to that end in SolveSpace, a free, multi-platform program that is primarily 3D but works fine for 2D and supports many levels of parametric design.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, kind of, but no actual locking is involved.

Select the just nodes of the segments you want to resize. You can use the Edit Paths by Nodes Tool, by clicking and dragging to select them, then move them by clicking and dragging while holding down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> to constrain the move horizontally/vertically.

[image]